# *** _pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have a directory of a thousand of pickle files  that I load one by one as follow :

I'm using python3

```
import pickle
for data in directory:
    with open(data,'rb') as handle:
         pickled_data=pickle.load(handle)
```

However, I get the following error for some files :

***** _pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncate**d

**What is wrong ?**

Data are stored as follow :

```
with open(filename,'wb') as handle:
     pickle.dump(data,handle,protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Thank you

Comment: um, what's `load.pickle`??? is that suppose to be `pickle.load`?

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo. Indeed, it is pickle.load

Comment: It could be that your files are corrupted

Comment: For which reason ?

Comment: @Taylor did you ever find the reason?  I experienced this too, and I'm guessing it's because the process didn't finish saving the file.